# How to measure the nut size that goes on screw?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, safety

I recently bought a toilet seat and the seat holder on one side loses over time making it loose from one side while another side is tight. I realised I was missing one these [image: nht cover] and hex Nut to fight it. I was wondering if the holder is loose because of the following

1. Hex nut too tight it
2. The displayed cover to cover the hex nut

I am new at this and wanted to find out about how do I determine the nut sizes? As the one I tried on the screw are too big or small. I am a layman at DIY so what is the best way to determine which nut goes on the screw? and if the attached image of the cover is needed or optional?

Comment: The nut could keep it from staying up if the seat won't stay properly leveled. You can usually buy just the nuts from a harware store. But if the nut isn't tight enough, the seat won't stay level, allowing the rear portion to drop to the ceramic rim, and allowing the cover to tip forward and close.

Comment: I have posted a update on question.

Comment: I presume it is a new toilet seat, that did not come with a parts diagram nor makers name? Otherwise it is just a hex nut with a fancy cover/tightening handle that makes it work like a wing nut.

Comment: @Jack Yes it is new, It came with part diagram but I think, I didn't see any second fancy covering, Every time the seat is open or closed (IMO), the hex nut that doesn't have the cover, drops a circle.

Comment: If you mean drops a thread, as in comes loose without turning it, you may have a metric thread over a standard thread or vice versa. It should be 1/4" diameter, I do not know of any seats that come with metric nuts, that's why the manufactures' name can be important. Or the bolt or the nut could be stripped, but not likely.

Comment: What you have in essence, is a hex nut in a plastic or porcelain cover

Comment: That nut cover has nothing to do with the lid being loose, it is the tightness of the nut within it that goes on the threads. The cover is just that, a cover.

Comment: @Jack The hex nut is not too tight?

Comment: Decorative wing-nut it looks like - but you can just get a nut at a hardware store and put it on (don't wrench too hard). The seat might not be staying up because it's too far back/hits the tank at a bad angle?

Comment: @bombcar how bad is bad angle

Comment: @nofel if you loosen the other nut, and push the seat as far forward as it will go, does it stay open correctly?

Comment: Just as a mention, it is not only the nut that goes on under the toilet rim to hold the seat on, there is typically a plastic washer with a metal washer over it to set the nut that holds it all together. Also, get it too tight and it may crack the rim. But the holes are usually much larger than needed in the toilet to pull the seat forward as suggested by @bombcar. In some toilets seats, the washers allow the small nut to "bridge" the bigger hole in the ceramic toilet. Really just knowing the brand of toilet would be helpful. Second guessing makes for a lot of words to cover everything.

Comment: To answer an earlier question, it sounds like it is not capable of staying tight enough if it slips on the threads, or circle, as you described.

Comment: @Jack I reassessed it and I will be editing the question to my new findings.